# Undefined local variable or method for Class after pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have numerous paginations in my application; they all look alike; all but one work fine. The one broken one breaks at the very last step. The details are below. I have 3 classes- Micropost, Category,  Selection.  I have a link that points to details_controller, which renders a view /selections/detailslist which in turn renders the partial /selections/details. The code successfully gets to the last view and breaks in the third line, with the error message "undefined local variable or method `micropost' for #<#< Class: ...."  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :category_content, :selection_content, :category_id, :selection_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :selection
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :category_content, presence: true
  validates :selection_content, presence: true
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :id, :count, :c_count
  has_many :selections
  has_many :microposts
end

class Selection < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :count, :category_id
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :microposts
end
```

view with link

```
<li>
  <span class="selection">
    <%= selection.content %>
    &nbsp &nbsp
    ( <%= selection.count %> )
    &nbsp   &nbsp
    <%= link_to "Details", controller: :details, param1: selection.id, param2: selection.category_id %>
  </span>
</li>
```

details_controller

```
class DetailsController < ApplicationController
  require 'will_paginate/array'
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    #@category = Category.find_by_id(params[:param2])
    @selection = Selection.find_by_id(params[:param1])
    @microposts = @selection.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render '/selections/detailslist'
  end
end
```

view: /selections/detailslist

```
<% @category = Category.find_by_id(@selection.category_id) %>
<h3> <%= @category.content %>   </h3>
    <br>
    <%= @selection.content %>
    &nbsp
    ( <%= @selection.count %> )
    <br>
<ol class="selections">
  <%= render partial: 'selections/details', collection: @microposts %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @microposts %>
```

view: selections/details

```
<li>
  <span class="selection">
    <% user = User.find_by_id(micropost.user_id) %>
    <%= user.name %>
  </span>
</li>
```

error message:
undefined local variable or method `micropost' for #<#< Class:0x007fed1811ba90>:0x007fed17bc9fb0>

Comment: I think you missed an @: User.find_by_id(@micropost.user_id)

Comment: Try with `<%= render partial: 'selections/details', collection: @microposts, as: :micropost %>`

Comment: Thanks to our wonderful SD Ruby community, problem is solved- "you need to variable name in the partial to be the same as the partial file."